# Been in or to Buckingham Palace

Tags: prepositions

I know that native speakers say "I have never **been to** Paris". Do we also use the structure **been to** when we talk about more specific places like: "I have never **been to** Buckingham Palace" or we can/have to use "I have never **been in** Buckingham Palace"?

How about "I haven't been to/in this place yet"?

Comment: Yoy can use both..,  “to” is probably the more common preposition.

Comment: "I've never been in**side** Buckingham Palace" makes the meaning clearer that you're referring to a guided tour which includes the rooms of the royal residence.

Comment: Related: ["I have been to France." vs. "I have been in France."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296344/i-have-been-to-france-vs-i-have-been-in-france)